# WAS server - attach policy set to a single JAX-WS client

Tags: security, websphere, jax-ws, ws-security

I have a java project **(*.jar)** that has code for 10 JAX-WS clients. **One of the clients uses WS-Security and needs policy set/bindings** to be attached to  it. Remaining nine clients use plain HTTP without any security to invoke respective services.

I used instructions from *http://www.redbooks.ibm.com/redbooks/pdfs/sg247758.pdf section 6.5* and configured **local/developer RAD workspace**, such that the policy set/bindings are associated only to the secure service client, and am able to invoke all services successfully.

However, in our **QA environment**, from **WAS Admin Console** am unable to associate the policy set/binding to the specific service. It is **either all or none**. That is, either I can attach the policy set to all 10 clients, and the secure client works OR I can detach the policy set and remaining 9 HTTP clients will work.

Can you help me understand why i am not able to attach the policy set to the secure service alone?

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 1):

IBM confirmed that it was a defect in WebSphere Application server v 7.0.0.13.
The regular expression matcher that attached the policy set/bindings to a JAX-WS call was not working. Hence we could not attach it to an individual service, but it worked when we attached it to the entire EAR.

IBM provided us with a fix